# how to get the fix substring from dynamic string content?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am developing VB.NET windows app. in VS  2010.

I want to get the substring

> $CostCenterId|4^10

from the below string .

> PaymentMode|NEFT^$IsPaid|False^$Currency|INR-Indian
>   Rupee^$CostCenterId|4^10$LedgerId|2^3$

The position of current string ($CostCenterId|4^10) in the sequence  may be change.
but it will always between the two $ sign. 
I have written the below code, but confused abt what to write next ?

```
Public Sub GetSubstringData()

   dim sfullString = "PaymentMode|NEFT^$IsPaid|False^$Currency|INR-Indian  
    Rupee^$CostCenterId|4^10$LedgerId|2^3$"

     Dim CostIndex As Integer
     CostIndex = sDiscription.IndexOf("CostCenterId")
     sDiscription.Substring(CostIndex,

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into the [Split function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of a string. This allows you to split a string into substrings based on a specified delimiting character.

You can then do this:

```
Dim sfullString = "PaymentMode|NEFT^$IsPaid|False^$Currency|INR-Indian Rupee^$CostCenterId|4^10$LedgerId|2^3$"
Debug.WriteLine("$" + sfullString.Split("$"c)(3))
```

Result: `$CostCenterId|4^10`

You will probably want to do some error checking to make sure the string actually contains the data you expect though.

However looking at the data, what you have is a string containing key-value pairs so you would be better to have a property to hold the `CostCenterId` and extract the data like this:

```
Public Property CostCenterId As String

Public Sub Decode(ByVal code As String)
    For Each pair As String In code.Split("$"c)
        If pair.Length > 0 AndAlso pair.Contains("|") Then
            Dim key As String = pair.Split("|"c)(0)
            Dim value As String = pair.Split("|"c)(1)
            Select Case key
                Case "CostCenterId"
                    Me.CostCenterId = value
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then call it like this:

```
Decode("PaymentMode|NEFT^$IsPaid|False^$Currency|INR-Indian Rupee^$CostCenterId|4^10$LedgerId|2^3$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not split() the string by $ into an array, and then look for the element which contains CostCenterId

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim CostIndex As Integer
CostIndex = sDiscription.IndexOf("CostCenterId")

auxNum = sDiscription.IndexOf("$"c, CostIndex) - CostIndex
sResult = sDiscription.SubString(CostIndex, auxNum)
```

Comment: The `c` indicates that the character on the left must be treated as a character instead of a string. Is the way of VB.NET to put chars directly. You can use it without this if you want, treating it like a `String`, it will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Dim token = "$CostCenterId"
Dim costIndexStart As Integer = sfullString.IndexOf(token)
Dim costIndexEnd As Integer = sfullString.IndexOf("$", costIndexStart + token.Length)
Dim cost As String = sfullString.Substring(costIndexStart, costIndexEnd - costIndexStart + 1)
```

Result: `"$CostCenterId|4^10$"`

If you want to omit the dollar-signs:

```
Substring(costIndexStart + 1, costIndexEnd - costIndexStart - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string,

```
Dim xString = "PaymentMode|NEFT^$IsPaid|False^$Currency|INR-Indian Rupee^$CostCenterId|4^10$LedgerId|2^3$"
```

Substring process,

```
 xString = xString.Substring(xString.IndexOf("$CostCenter"), xString.IndexOf("$", xString.IndexOf("$CostCenter") + 1) - xString.IndexOf("$CostCenter"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
  Dim sfullString = "PaymentMode|NEFT^$IsPaid|False^$Currency|INR-Indian" _
    & "Rupee^$CostCenterId|4^10$LedgerId|2^3$"

        Dim sp() As String = {"$"}
        Dim ar() As String = sfullString.Split(sp, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Array.Sort(ar)
        MsgBox("$" & ar(0))
```